# \n doesn't work in " "

Tags: php, echo

My code:

```
<?php
$country = array(
             'zh' => array( 'tw' => "Traditional Chinese"),
             'zh' => array( 'cn' => "Simplified Chinese"),
             'en' => "English",
             'jp' => "Japanese"
           );
echo $country['zh']['tw']."\n".$country['zh']['cn']."\n".$country['en']."\n".$country['jp'];
```

My result: [image: is here].

Why I use "" but \n doesn't work?

By the way, I try

```
echo "{$country['zh']['tw']}\n{$country['zh']['cn']}\n{$country['en']}\n{$country['jp']}"
```

It's still the same...

Comment: "\n" do not work in HTML. You have to use `<br>`

Comment: it's php not html

Comment: But you print it to a browser as i can see in the screenshot. And the browser renders html

Answer (score 0):

The browser does not show line breaks by default for HTML files.
You can either use

```
<pre>
```

tag in front of your php script part or

```
header("content-type: text/plain")
```

to force the file to be interpreted as text file.